# Eigen::Tensor and Eigen::Matrix performance comparison

Tags: c++, tensorflow, eigen

I would like to replace a sequence of matrices in my code with a single 3-D Eigen::Tensor. With this in mind, I try to compare Tensor and Matrix performances.

Function "tensorContractTest" below performs a contraction of (n,n,n) rank 3 tensor with a rank 1 tensor of size n (n = 500). This  contraction computes n**2 dot products, so in terms of  the number of operations, it is equivalent to multiplication of two (n,n) matrices (function "matrixProductTest" below).

When run on Visual Studio 2013, function "tensorContractTest" runs ~ 40 times slower than "matrixProductTest". 
Probably, I am missing something. Help is appreciated.

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
using namespace Eigen;

// Contracts 3-dimensional (n x n x n) tensor with 1-dimensional (n) tensor. 
// By the number of operations, it's equivalent to multiplication of 
// two (n, n) matrices (matrixProdTest).
Tensor<double, 2>  tensorContractTest(int n)
{
  Tensor<double, 3> a(n, n, n);     a.setConstant(1.);  
  Tensor<double, 1> b(n);           b.setConstant(1.);
  auto indexPair            = array<IndexPair<int>, 1>{IndexPair<int>(2,0)}; 
  Tensor<double, 2> result  = a.contract(b, indexPair); 
  return result;
}

MatrixXd  matrixProductTest(int n)
{ 
  MatrixXd a = MatrixXd::Ones(n, n), result = a * a;
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you enable optimizations?  Please also provide a proper benchmark using, e.g. [Google Benchmark](https://github.com/google/benchmark), rather than just throwing numbers out there.

Comment: I used /O2 compiler flag. My timing function is below.

#include <chrono></br>
#include <utility><br/>
#include <iostream><br>

// Timing function<br>
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point  TimeVar;<br>
#define duration(a)   std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(a).count()
#define timeNow()     std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now()

template<typename F, typename... Args> double funcTime(F func, Args&&... args)
{
    TimeVar t1 = timeNow();
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return duration(timeNow() - t1);
}

Comment: @HenriMenke. I used /O2 compiler flag.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the number of floating point operations are of same order, the memory access pattern are completely different and so the two operations are not comparable at all. Generally speaking matrix-matrix operation will always be faster (in terms of FLOPS) than matrix-vector or vector-vector operations because the former enable better cache usage and thus a nearly optimal usage of the CPU's ALU. In you case, on one side you have to read a n^3 tensor versus two n^2 matrices, so the memory footprints are not comparable at all.

Internally, `Tensor::contract` fallback to Eigen's matrix product kernels when possible, so performance should be in pair.

Answer (score 1):

Because Tensor contraction is not the same as matrix multiplication.

There exists spetialized algorithms for matrix multiplication such as the Strassen algorithm that reduce the total number of operations. Also matrix libraries have been highly optimized over the years, so they are usually spetialized for using vectorized instructions (SIMD or AVX) depending on the platform (Intel, AMD, ARM). For matrices of small sizes or with sparse patterns the speed gain is huge compared with non-spetialized code.

Instead Tensor libraries tend to be less optimized in comparison. So if you can cast your tensor math to matrix algebra, there are many chances that speed are going to increase.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the slowness with a google benchmark program. As I tested, if the data size is small, Eigen's matrix multiplication is faster than Eigen's tensor contract. The results will be the same, though.

[image]

So I'm not sure about the fallback

> Internally, Tensor::contract fallback to Eigen's matrix product kernels when possible, so performance should be in pair.

@ggael mentioned here.

---

Here's my test code:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <benchmark/benchmark.h>
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>

constexpr std::size_t I = ;
constexpr std::size_t J = ;
constexpr std::size_t K = ;

static void bmForLoop(benchmark::State &state) {
  // Perform setup here
  Eigen::Matrix<double, I, J> m_0 = Eigen::Matrix<double, I, J>::Random();
  Eigen::Matrix<double, J, K> m_1 = Eigen::Matrix<double, J, K>::Random();
  Eigen::Matrix<double, I, K> m_2;

  for (auto _ : state) {
    // This code gets timed
    m_2 = Eigen::Matrix<double, I, K>::Zero();
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < I; ++i) {
      for (std::size_t k = 0; k < K; ++k) {
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < J; ++j) {
          benchmark::DoNotOptimize(m_2.coeffRef(i, k) +=
                                   m_0.coeff(i, j) * m_1.coeff(j, k));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

static void bmEigenMatrix(benchmark::State &state) {
  // Perform setup here
  Eigen::Matrix<double, I, J> m_0 = Eigen::Matrix<double, I, J>::Random();
  Eigen::Matrix<double, J, K> m_1 = Eigen::Matrix<double, J, K>::Random();
  Eigen::Matrix<double, I, K> m_2;

  for (auto _ : state) {
    // This code gets timed
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(m_2 = m_0 * m_1);
  }
}

static void bmEigenMatrixDynamic(benchmark::State &state) {
  // Perform setup here
  Eigen::MatrixXd m_0(I, J);
  m_0 = Eigen::Matrix<double, I, J>::Random();
  Eigen::MatrixXd m_1(J, K);
  m_1 = Eigen::Matrix<double, J, K>::Random();
  Eigen::MatrixXd m_2;

  for (auto _ : state) {
    // This code gets timed
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(m_2 = m_0 * m_1);
  }
}

static void bmEigenTensorFixed(benchmark::State &state) {
  // Perform setup here
  Eigen::Matrix<double, I, J> m_0 = Eigen::Matrix<double, I, J>::Random();
  Eigen::Matrix<double, J, K> m_1 = Eigen::Matrix<double, J, K>::Random();
  Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::TensorFixedSize<double, Eigen::Sizes<I, J>>> t_0(
      m_0.data(), I, J);
  Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::TensorFixedSize<double, Eigen::Sizes<J, K>>> t_1(
      m_1.data(), J, K);
  Eigen::TensorFixedSize<double, Eigen::Sizes<I, K>> t_2;

  for (auto _ : state) {
    // This code gets timed
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(
        t_2 = t_0.contract(
            t_1, Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<Eigen::Index>, 1>{{{1, 0}}}));
  }
}

static void bmEigenTensor(benchmark::State &state) {
  // Perform setup here
  Eigen::Matrix<double, I, J> m_0 = Eigen::Matrix<double, I, J>::Random();
  Eigen::Matrix<double, J, K> m_1 = Eigen::Matrix<double, J, K>::Random();
  Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>> t_0(m_0.data(), I, J);
  Eigen::TensorMap<Eigen::Tensor<double, 2>> t_1(m_1.data(), J, K);
  Eigen::Tensor<double, 2> t_2;

  for (auto _ : state) {
    // This code gets timed
    benchmark::DoNotOptimize(
        t_2 = t_0.contract(
            t_1, Eigen::array<Eigen::IndexPair<Eigen::Index>, 1>{{{1, 0}}}));
  }
}

BENCHMARK(bmForLoop);
BENCHMARK(bmEigenMatrix);
BENCHMARK(bmEigenMatrixDynamic);
BENCHMARK(bmEigenTensorFixed);
BENCHMARK(bmEigenTensor);
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

, where I, J, and K

```
constexpr std::size_t I = ;
constexpr std::size_t J = ;
constexpr std::size_t K = ;
```

are filled with the same number, ranging from 1 to 8.

I use Bazel to compile, and the compilation command is `build --cxxopt=-std=c++17 --cxxopt=-march=native --cxxopt=-O3 --cxxopt=-DNDEBUG`. Eigen's version is 3.4.0.