# Numpy 3D Array/Eigen Tensor C++, multiply each row by its transpose

Tags: numpy, eigen

Say I had a numpy array `A` of shape `(55, 50, 2)`, and I would like to do the following operation

```
B = np.dot(A[0, :, 0][:, None], A[0, :, 0][None, :])
```

i.e. compute the dot product of each row by its transpose (over i and k)

Without the use of `np.einsum` and obviously any for loops, how can this operation be done by pure broadcasting and reshaping (if needed)?

**Note:**

Im tagging `eigen3` here because essentially I would want to rewrite this operation with `Eigen::Tensor` in terms of `.broadcast()` and `.reshape()` (Its easier for me to write it out in `numpy` first to get the general picture) . So a direct `Eigen` solution would be much appreciated, but since python, hence numpy, is more popular, I would accept a numpy solution as well.

Comment: What's wrong with the method you showed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, then this operation can be done using the Eigen::Tensor module as follows

```cpp
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
int main(){
    // Define a tensor
    Eigen::Tensor<double,3> A(55,50,2);
    A.setRandom();

    // Define the pairs of indices to multiply (i.e. index 1 on A twice)
    std::array<Eigen::IndexPair<long>, 1> idx = { Eigen::IndexPair<long> {1, 1} };
    
    // Contract. B will have dimensions [55,2,55,2]
    Eigen::Tensor<double,4> B = A.contract(A, idx);
}
```

[See on compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/ExfcYafhP).

Parallel execution can be done with a small modification:

```cpp
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
int main(){
    // Define a tensor
    Eigen::Tensor<double,3> A(55,50,2);
    A.setRandom();

    // Define the pairs of indices to multiply (i.e. index 1 on A twice)
    std::array<Eigen::IndexPair<long>, 1> idx = { Eigen::IndexPair<long> {1, 1} };
    
    // Define a parallel device 
    int num_threads = 4;
    Eigen::ThreadPool       tpl (num_threads);
    Eigen::ThreadPoolDevice dev (&tpl, num_threads);

    // Initialize result buffer B. B will have dimensions [55,2,55,2]
    Eigen::Tensor<double,4> B(55,2,55,2);

    // Contract using the parallel device
    B.device(dev) = A.contract(A, idx);
}
```

[See on compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/9WTrfzM8b). Note the compiler flags, in particular `-DEIGEN_USE_THREADS`. Also, I had to set -O0 because -O3 timed out.

On the topic of performance discussed in the comments: In my experience with it daily for the last ~4 years, the contractions using the Eigen::Tensor module perform very well, I haven't been able to find/produce anything faster (i.e. for dense, dynamically-sized tensors on shared memory). According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48114508/6248145) (by the original author of Eigen), the contractions fall back to the matrix product kernels when possible, which should give some confidence. In this case you can use any [BLAS library as backend](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicUsingBlasLapack.html).

Comment: Yes, this is it chief. been waiting for an answer like this. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

So what you need is an outer product for each row.

It is better to write loops and do a matrix multiplication if you are using C++ Eigen. You can dispatch to BLAS for performance.

If you want a way using Numpy, a messy solution is

```
B = A[...,newaxis].transpose(0,2,1,3)
C = B@B.transpose(0,1,3,2) #Matrix multiplication
C = C.transpose(0,3,2,1)
np.array_equal(np.einsum('ijk,ilk->ijlk',A,A),C) ## check if both are identical
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer works as needed. Do you have any experiences with comparing  SIMD with `Eigen::Tensor` and for loops with the standard `Eigen::MatrixXd`. If so, which was better?

Comment: My experience is very limited with Eigen. Maybe you can write two simple for loops and cast them into VectorXd to perform the outer product. you can use -O3 flag to turn on compiler optimizations. If you can link some high performance BLAS to Eigen, you can get much better performance. You can compare this with the Numpy code to check if it is effective.